# how to get 2 values out of a string

Tags: powershell

Im hoping someone can help me with where to start, I want to pull some data out of some larger data
My data looks like this:

```
IP-MIB::ipNetToMediaPhysAddress.13600001.10.4.48.1 = STRING: 36:b:7:0:41:31
IP-MIB::ipNetToMediaPhysAddress.13600001.10.4.49.21 = STRING: 3b:fa:a2:us:74:d9
IP-MIB::ipNetToMediaPhysAddress.13600001.10.3.50.22 = STRING: 3b:fa:a2:us:7b:f3
```

There is an IP Address on each line starting with 10. and the mac address which is on the end, thats what I want to get out.
Ive been googling and am not sure where to start/what to do.
Is Regex the way to go, or is there a better way, any examples would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

here's one way to get that info ... [*grin*]

- fake reading in a text file
  you will most likely want to use `Get-Content` or some pre-existing collection.
- iterate thru the collection
- use a named-capture-group regex to match on the IP & MAC
- create a PSCustomObject from the match data
  you can get them from the `$Matches` automatic variable.
- send the current object out to be collected by the $Results variable
- display that collection

here's the code ...

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
IP-MIB::ipNetToMediaPhysAddress.13600001.10.4.48.1 = STRING: 36:b:7:0:41:31
IP-MIB::ipNetToMediaPhysAddress.13600001.10.4.49.21 = STRING: 3b:fa:a2:us:74:d9
IP-MIB::ipNetToMediaPhysAddress.13600001.10.3.50.22 = STRING: 3b:fa:a2:us:7b:f3
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

$Results = foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    $Null = $IS_Item -match '\.\d{8}\.(?<IPv4>.+) = .+: (?<MacAddress>.+)$'
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        IPv4 = $Matches.IPv4
        MacAddress = $Matches.MacAddress
        }
    }

$Results
```

you can use `Export-CSV` to send that to a nicely structured CSV file.

Comment: Thanks Lee much appreciated, think you could explain regex to me, at least in the example you provided, or is it to hard of a concept?

Comment: @Bill - you are most welcome! i'm not very good at explaining regex, so i refer you to this site ... https://regex101.com //// go there and paste the regex pattern into the center top box [without the surrounding single quotes], and the `Explanation` box on the far right will show what each step does. ///// if you want to see it in action, you can also paste your sample into the 2nd box in the center. [*grin*]